# How to construct a list of all Fibonacci numbers less than n in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like to write a Mathematica function that constructs a list of all Fibonacci numbers less than n.  Moreover, I would like to do this as elegantly and functionally as possible(so without an explicit loop).

Conceptually I want to take an infinite list of the natural numbers, map Fib[n] onto it, and then take elements from this list while they are less than n.  How can I do this in Mathematica?

Comment: Are you wanting permission to do so? If so, please consider it given. :-) If that's not what you're asking, please ask an actual, specific question (there's no question in your post now) and post the code you've written trying to accomplish this yourself, and we can help with the specific problems you're having with that code.

Comment: Although easy, it _is_ a real question now ("How can I do this in Mathematica?)". Voting to reopen

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi it appears to be re-opened. Enjoy.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi Please be sure to have your insurance bills up to date before trying to store an infinite list anywhere. :)

Answer (score 3):

The first part can be done fairly easily in *Mathematica*. Below, I provide two functions `nextFibonacci`, which provides the next Fibonacci number greater than the input number (just like `NextPrime`) and `fibonacciList`, which provides a list of all Fibonacci numbers less than the input number.

```
ClearAll[nextFibonacci, fibonacciList]
nextFibonacci[m_] := Fibonacci[
    Block[{n}, 
        NArgMax[{n, 1/Sqrt[5] (GoldenRatio^n - (-1)^n GoldenRatio^-n) <= m, n ∈ Integers}, n]
    ] + 1
]
nextFibonacci[1] := 2;

fibonacciList[m_] := Fibonacci@
    Range[0, Block[{n}, 
      NArgMax[{n, 1/Sqrt[5] (GoldenRatio^n - (-1)^n GoldenRatio^-n) < m, n ∈ Integers}, n]
    ]
]
```

Now you can do things like:

```
nextfibonacci[15]
(* 21 *)

fibonacciList[50]
(* {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34} *)
```

The second part though, is tricky. What you're looking for is a Haskell type lazy evaluation that will only evaluate if and when necessary (as otherwise, you can't hold an infinite list in memory). For example, something like (in Haskell):

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

which then allows you to do things like

```
take 10 fibs
-- [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]

takeWhile (<100) fibs
-- [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
```

Unfortunately, there is no built-in support for what you want. However, you can extend *Mathematica* to implement lazy style lists as shown in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/885), which was also [implemented as a package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4093). Now that you have all the pieces that you need, I'll let you work on this yourself.

Comment: I see. Now that the empire has become ascendant, you have decided to hide behind a veil of anonymity. Clever, very clever.

Comment: I'm just a mouse with no name (a horse might've been better)... some day, I shall scamper away from this site for good, in search of better cheese.

Answer (score 3):

If you grab my [Lazy package](https://github.com/sblom/mathematica-lazy) from GitHub, your solution is as simple as:

```
Needs["Lazy`"]
LazySource[Fibonacci] ~TakeWhile~ ((# < 1000) &) // List
```

If you want to slightly more literally implement your original description

> Conceptually I want to take an infinite list of the natural numbers, map Fib[n] onto it, and then take elements from this list while they are less than n.

you could do it as follows:

```
Needs["Lazy`"]
Fibonacci ~Map~ Lazy[Integers] ~TakeWhile~ ((# < 1000) &) // List
```

To prove that this is completely lazy, try the previous example without the `// List` on the end. You'll see that it stops with the (rather ugly) form:

```
LazyList[First[ 
  LazyList[Fibonacci[First[LazyList[1, LazySource[#1 &, 2]]]], 
   Fibonacci /@ Rest[LazyList[1, LazySource[#1 &, 2]]]]], 
 TakeWhile[
  Rest[LazyList[Fibonacci[First[LazyList[1, LazySource[#1 &, 2]]]], 
    Fibonacci /@ Rest[LazyList[1, LazySource[#1 &, 2]]]]], #1 < 
    1000 &]]
```

This consists of a `LazyList[]` expression whose first element is the first value of the expression that you're lazily evaluating and whose second element is instructions for how to continue the expansion.

### Improvements

It's a little bit inefficient to continually call `Fibonacci[n]` all the time, especially as `n` starts getting large. It's actually possible to construct a lazy generator that will calculate the current value of the Fibonacci sequence as we stream:

```
Needs["Lazy`"]

LazyFibonacci[a_,b_]:=LazyList[a,LazyFibonacci[b,a+b]]
LazyFibonacci[]:=LazyFibonacci[1,1]

LazyFibonacci[] ~TakeWhile~ ((# < 1000)&) // List
```

Finally, we could generalize this up to a more abstract generating function that takes an initial value for an accumulator, a `List` of `Rule`s to compute the accumulator's value for the next step and a `List` of `Rule`s to compute the result from the current accumulator value.

```
LazyGenerator[init_, step_, extract_] := 
 LazyList[Evaluate[init /. extract], 
  LazyGenerator[init /. step, step, extract]]
```

And could use it to generate the Fibonacci sequence as follows:

```
LazyGenerator[{1, 1}, {a_, b_} :> {b, a + b}, {a_, b_} :> a]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I hope I understood the question. But please note, I am not pure math major, I am mechanical engineering student. But this sounded interesting. So I looked up the formula and this is what I can come up with now. I have to run, but if there is a bug, please let me know and I will fix it.

This manipulate asks for `n` and then lists all Fibonacci numbers less than n. There is no loop to find how many  Fibonacci numbers there are less than `n`. It uses `Reduce` to solve for the number of Fibonacci numbers less than `n`. I take the floor of the result and also threw away a constant that came up with in the solution a complex multiplier.

And then simply makes a table of all these numbers using Mathematica `Fibonacci` command.  So if you enter `n=20` it will list `1,1,2,3,5,8,13` and so on. I could do it for infinity as I ran out of memory (I only have 8 GB ram on my pc).

I put the limit for `n` to `500000` Feel free to edit the code and change it.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{k, m}, 
  k = Floor@N[Assuming[Element[m, Integers] && m > 0, 
        Reduce[f[m] == n, m]][[2, 1, 2]] /. Complex[0, 2] -> 0];
  TableForm@Join[{{"#", "Fibonacci number" }}, 
    Table[{i, Fibonacci[i]}, {i, 1, k}]]
  ],

  {{n, 3, "n="}, 2, 500000, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small}, 
  SynchronousUpdating -> False, 
  ContentSize -> {200, 500}, Initialization :>
  {
   \[CurlyPhi][n_] := ((1 + Sqrt[5])/2)^n;
   \[Psi][n_] := -(1/\[CurlyPhi][n]);
   f[n_] := (\[CurlyPhi][n] - \[Psi][n])/Sqrt[5];
   }]
```

Screen shot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

The index k of the Fibonacci number Fk is `k=Floor[Log[GoldenRatio,Fk]*Sqrt[5]+1/2]]`,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number. Hence, the list of Fibonacci numbers less than *or equal to* n is

```
 FibList[n_Integer]:=Fibonacci[Range[Floor[Log[GoldenRatio,Sqrt[5]*n+1/2]]]]
```